# Why is a tangent line showing when I plot certain circular Unicode symbols in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rendering

I am plotting the phases of the Moon using Unicode symbols in Matplotlib.  When I use the two half-filled circles, \u25D0 and \u25D1, they both render with a small tangent line in the bottom left corner.  The other two filled circles, \u25CF and \u25CB don't have this problem.  Any idea what might be causing this problem?

[image: phases of the Moon]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ephem

today = '2020/05/20'
markersize=80

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

newMoon = ephem.localtime(ephem.next_new_moon(today))
fullMoon = ephem.localtime(ephem.next_full_moon(today))
firstQuarter = ephem.localtime(ephem.next_first_quarter_moon(today))
lastQuarter = ephem.localtime(ephem.next_last_quarter_moon(today))

ax.plot(newMoon,1,markeredgecolor='black',markerfacecolor='black',markersize=markersize,marker='$\u25CF$')
ax.plot(fullMoon,1,markeredgecolor='black',markerfacecolor='black',markersize=markersize,marker='$\u25CB$')
ax.plot(firstQuarter,1,markeredgecolor='black',markerfacecolor='black',markersize=markersize,marker='$\u25D0$')
ax.plot(lastQuarter,1,markeredgecolor='black',markerfacecolor='black',markersize=markersize,marker='$\u25D1$')

ax.margins(.2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `markeredgecolor = 'white'` for the `firstQuarter` and the `lastQuarter`.

Comment: With more testing, it seems to be causing problems by making the edges too thin now.  Might you have any other suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: You could alsos try to set the markeredgecolor as 'None', this means that no color should be used, and also the edges would not be that thin.

Comment: When I tried that, it randomly assigned colors to the edges, and brought the tangents line back.

Comment: Be careful, use markeredgecolor = 'None' not markeredgecolor  = None. In Matplotlib 'None' means no color should be used, while None is default.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.   This solution worked the best.  It is still rendering a bit irregularly in the bottom left, but I can live with it.